# Simple bootstrap with replacement of list

Tags: python, random

I'm attempting to perform a simple bootstrap process with replacement applied to a list formatted like so:

```
a = [[0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8], [0.3,0.7,0.1,0.6], [0.3,1.2,1.0,0.6], ....]
```

That is: `a` is a list made of `N` sublists each with the same number of floats (4 in this case)

In order to choose random elements (ie: *sub-lists*) from `a` with replacement to perform the bootstrap process I can do:

```
import random

bts_a = []
for elem in a:
    r = random.randint(0,len(a))
    bts_a.append(a[r])
```

Is there a more succinct and/or faster way to accomplish this? I particulary dislike having to initialize an empty list (ie: `bts_a=[]`), it feels very non-pythonic to me.

Comment: You should probably take a look at [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: The most direct tranlation to *pythonic* code was `bts_a = [ a[random.randint(0,len(a)-1)] for elem in range(len(a)) ]`. This is not worse but also in no way better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) and list comprehension or map:

```
a = [[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8], [0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.6], [0.3, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6]]

>>> [random.choice(e) for e in a]
[0.5, 0.6, 0.6]
>>> [random.choice(e) for e in a]
[0.4, 0.3, 1.2]

>>> map(random.choice, a)
[0.5, 0.1, 1.0]
>>> map(random.choice, a)
[0.8, 0.3, 0.3]
```

to choose random sublist from a:

```
>>> random.choice(a)
[0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.6]
>>> random.choice(a)
[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8]

bts_a = [random.choice(a) for _ in a]
>>> bts_a
[[0.3, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6], [0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8], [0.3, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6]]
```

Comment: I'm not trying to select random floats from each sub-list, I'm trying to select random _sub-lists_ from `a`.

Comment: @Gabriel `random.choice` anyway, check updated answer

Comment: Ok, I've used `random.choice` which seems to be the recommended way to go about this and came up with this line: `bts_a = [random.choice(a) for _ in a]`. If you like, you can add it to your answer, it replaces the full `for` loop I presented in the question. Cheers.

Comment: thanks. I'm not getting the reason to use `for _ in range(len(a))` instead of simply `for _ in a`. Could you explain the difference between these approaches?

Comment: @Gabriel hm, you are right, actually it is a little slower (with xrange in python2) than `for _ in a`

Answer (score 2):

This will give you random sub-list using [random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> a = [[0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8], [0.3,0.7,0.1,0.6], [0.3,1.2,1.0,0.6]]
>>> print choice(a)
[0.3, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6]
>>>
```

**Or**

```
 >>> print a[int(random()*len(a))]
 [0.3, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6]
 >>> a
 [[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8], [0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.6], [0.3, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6]]
 >>> from random import random
 >>> print a[int(random()*len(a))]
 [0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8]
 >>> print a[int(random()*len(a))]
 [0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.6]
 >>>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is [random.shuffle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
random.shuffle(a)
```

Note that it changes the list inline. If you want a different list. You need to create a copy:

```
bts = a[:]
random.shuffle(bts)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8], [0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.6], [0.3, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6]]
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
[[0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.6], [0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8], [0.3, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6]]
```

Comment: `random.shuffle` only _moves_ elements around. With replacement means that some elements in the final list will be _repeated_. BTW I did not downvote your answer, I never downvote. Cheers and thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem. Why do you need to repeat elements anyway? There is a chance that some elements will never be repeated using random.choice() and a list comprehension so random.shuffle would be an equivalent to that.

Comment: Because that's what the bootstrap with replacement process does (you can Google it) Shuffling will never be an equivalent since it will _never_ repeat elements, not even a single one.

Comment: @AlexandruPlugaru: Shuffling will produce a sample with the _exact_ same statistical information (mean, variance, median, etc.) every single time, while sampling without replacement will produce a sample whose (mean, variance, etc.) are random variables centered around the original sample's statistics.

Comment: More importantly, sampling _with_ replacement produces values that are statistically independent of each other.